# ipdb: tracing via additional code on demand | python

Tags: python, ipdb

I use `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()`

Sometimes, while debugging with `set_trace` I want verify some method out of frame/source (invoke it with my parameters, and see how it works inside). Method is not used yet in code, so jump is impossible.

sth like:

```
def do_a(): ...
def do_b(): ...
def do_c(): ...

def do_d():
  do_a()
  import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
```

# here: wanna check do_c before do_b, but not just get result from do_c (it's easy), rather trace throught entire do_c and keep position in current frame.

```
  do_b()
```

there is `debug` command, but do not work with functions, I expect interactive shell.

Workaround is time-consuming: stop debugger, modify code (add do_c() in example) and restart debugger)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this works as this is quite rare use case.

Set breakpoint with breakpoint settings command like `tbreak`:

http://georgejhunt.com/olpc/pydebug/pydebug/ipdb.html

```
  tbreak do_b   # Might or might not work
```

Then just execute do_b and it should hit the breakpoint

```
  do_b()
```

Comment: nope, doesnt work - it's just breakpoint for code loaded in frame; I guess that I need use separate new frame for this (?), but this is not my level.

however I found pudb - nice alternative.